# How can I create an Outlook folder with local tasks, that are not synced to Exchange?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I'm currently working on an Outlook 2013 VSTO Addin.

I'm trying to add a folder containing tasks, which is NOT synced to the Exchange (2013) server (including its content). I want the tasks to show up only locally in Outlook 2013.

I have tried to add the folder with tasks like this:

```
IO.Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
IO.Outlook.MAPIFolder vorgangTaskFolder = null;
IO.Outlook.Items items = null;
IO.Outlook.TaskItem task = null;

ns = ThisAddIn.CurrentApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
IO.Outlook.Folder tasksFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(IO.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks) as IO.Outlook.Folder;
vorgangTaskFolder = tasksFolder.Folders.Add("ExampleFolderName", Type.Missing) as IO.Outlook.Folder;

vorgangTaskFolder.InAppFolderSyncObject = false;

foreach (var item in taskList)
{
    task = vorgangTaskFolder.Items.Add(IO.Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem) as IO.Outlook.TaskItem;
    task.Subject = item.Title;
    task.Body = item.VorgangsTitle;
    task.Save();
}
```

..but it seems like the InAppFolderSyncObject property did nothing, my tasks still ended up in OWA..

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that - everything in the primary mailbox will be synchronized with the server.

Why not add a PST store?

Comment: Thats something I haven't done yet. So its basically like creating a second mailbox that's stored locally? That could be an option, I will try that.

Comment: Yep, use Namespace.AddStore/AddStoreEX for that.